# Bash for loop - how can I include blank newlines? (IFS)

Tags: command-line, bash, ifs

Please note this is pseudocode, and I am not trying to count lines this way, this question is to figure out how to include completely blank newlines in a for loop.

`cat file`

```
word



word
```

**Since there are a total of 5 lines, x should equal 5 in the end.**

```
IFS=$'\n'
x=0
for line in $(cat file) ; do
x=$(($x+1))
done

echo $x
```

**However, the blank newlines are not being counted, and x equals 2 instead of 5.**

I thought the `IFS=$'\n'` would have made this work how I wanted. Can someone please explain how to make the blank newlines be "counted" in the for loop?

Comment: Do you want to use a loop for something or do you want to just count the number of lines?

Comment: Hey like I mentioned at the top, I'm not trying to count lines this way. I want to use a for loop for something, and I would like to count the blank newlines.  I thought this question was going to be asked :D

Comment: Also in the first case, I guess a `while` loop will work just as well, won't it?

Comment: I think in my case, I need a for loop, since I will be using the $line variables

Comment: It can be done with `while` as well, if that's ok I can write a `while` solution

Comment: Sure if it works! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `read` in a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    ((x++))
done < file
echo $x
exit 0
```

```
~$ cat file
word



word
~$ bash script.sh
5
```

Comment: Perfect!
Is there a reason why this works with a while read loop instead of a for loop?

Does it have to do with @muru's answer?

I'm assuming the while read loop reads it literally line by line..

Thanks again kos for another awesome answer

Comment: @TuxForLife Rephrasing: `read` just works because it's intended to work like that, it's not really comparable to how `$IFS` works, they are just two different things.

Comment: Hey kos, I wasn't able to get it working in my situation since it is a little more complicated. I probably do need a for loop. But I made a sneaky workaround lol. Using sed, I replaced all the empty lines with "BLANKLINEFILLER", ran the dependent command, and then replaced "BLANKLINEFILLER" with a blank line again :D

I feel bad not using anyone's solution, but this trick will suffice!

Comment: @TuxForLife What was the problem? Whitespaces other than newlines in "empty" lines?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure since there were a lot of factors. My input is a cat-ed file through a couple of pipes, and I wasn't sure how to input it into the while read loop. I don't think whitespaces were the issue however.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this using the shell's field splitting.

Adjacent whitespace characters from `IFS` are parsed together, so you cannot use field splitting to distinguish between adjacent whitespace IFS characters. From the standard (*Shell and Utilities*, [section 2.6.5](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05)):

> Each occurrence in the input of an IFS character that is not IFS white space, along with any adjacent IFS white space, shall delimit a field, as described previously.

That's just how it is.

Since this is a hypothetical question, and you haven't said what it is exactly that you're doing, I won't suggest another way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will need to use `while read line` instead:

```
x=0
while read line ; do
    x=$(($x+1))
done
```